# Use chartjs with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chart.js

I'd like to use chartjs with rails in a view, it works great, but when using an option like this one :

```
legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
```

rails will interpret <% and run name.toLowerCase() as a ruby code, which is actually javascript, how can I escape '<%' in rails?

Comment: Rails runs on your server, javascript runs in your user's browser.  You can use rails to BUILD javascript, to run on the client, but rails cannot access the javascript runtime.  Can you please explain (in an edit to your question, not a comment) what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: oh hang on, do you just mean "how to i convert a string to lowercase in rails?"  If that is your question the answer is `<%= name.downcase %>`

Comment: Nah you didn't get the point.. Hm, let's imagine I want to write <%= on a page, how do I escape this ? \<\%\= ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an extra percent sign:

```
<%%= @foo %> =>  "<%= @foo %>"
```

or

```
<%% foo %> => "<% foo %>"
```

BTW in case you want to start googling for stuff instead of using SO, i googled "escape erb tags" to get this, i'd not done it before.

Comment: BTW i'm curious as to what you're doing here, it seems quite ass-backwards.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a native english speaker, I didn't know what to type on google in order to find an answer to this, so I basically googled things like "escape ruby brackets", "escape ruby code in views".. I'm using this library : https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js if you look at line 491, you'll see that it uses the ruby tag, so when I write my code inside of a <script> in a view and use the erb tag, it f*cks everything up :p

Comment: I've never seen javascript building erb templates before, seems quite confusing.  Good luck!